# node js Insert into mysql variable not work

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am using MySql with node.js

i have this query and it works:

```
 connection.query('insert into username (name) values ("msg")', function(err,    rows, fields) {

    if(!err) {


     } });
```

it inserts the string `"msg"`, not the value of the variable `msg`, but when I want to insert the variable  this does not work:

```
connection.query('insert into username (name) values '+ msg, function(err,    rows, fields) {

    if(!err) {


     } });
```

for example:

> var msg  = "hello world!";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis and the quotes that make a valid insert statement in the second case. You are building a sql statement that looks like this:

```
'insert into username (name) values hello world'
```

which is malformed. Use the util module to make your string formatting easier:

```
var util - require('util');
var mySql = util.format('insert into username (name) values ("%s")', 'hello world');
connection.query(mySql, function(err,    rows, fields) {

if(!err) {


 } });
```

Comment: its insert  ("%s") !!

Comment: yes i change it before see edit and its work now thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'db_name'
});

connection.query(`INSERT INTO user_table (name, mail, pass) VALUES ('${user_name}', '${user_name}', '${user_name}');`, function (err, result, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  });
```